# Why is there a string saved in my serialized array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, serialization

Below is how I serialize my array.

```
$featured_image_id = $arg['thumbnail_id'];
$data = serialize( array( $featured_image_id ) );

update_post_meta( $arg['post_id'], 'images', $data );
```

What I get in my db table is `s:17:"a:1:{i:0;i:1955;}";` with a string in front.

How do I remove the string? I just need `"a:1:{i:0;i:1955;}"`

Comment: Why are you serializing this at all? Why not just store the `$featured_image_id` in your table?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular because one of the plugins requires the meta_value to be serialized.

Comment: I saw this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64721616/correct-way-to-insert-serialized-data-into-wordpress-post-meta-using-update-post but I still don't get the answer `$data   =    unserialize( 'YOUR_CODE_SERIALIZED_HERE' );` does it say it wants me to save the data as unserialized?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it.

I don't need to serialize the array. It will be serialized by update_post_meta function as according to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/

WordPress doc is always not clear. It should change from saying `"Metadata value. Must be serializable if non-scalar."` to `"Metadata value. Value will be automatically serialized if non-scalar."` [PHP doc](https://www.php.net/docs.php) is still the best.